# What will Typescript transpile when targeting ES5 / ES3?

Tags: typescript, target, transpiler

I'm trying to understand when the Typescript compiler will transpile code to make it compatible with my specified target ECMAScript version (ES5 or ES3).

For example, TSC will transpile `for(var int of intArray)` fine, but it doesn't transpile `Number.isInteger()` (which is an ES6 feature, according to [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_isinteger.asp)).

`Number.isInteger()` isn't supported in IE < 11.0, so this is a problem. Visual Studio (and VS Code) don't provide warnings of incompatibility, and it doesn't get transpiled.

What can I expect to get transpiled, and what won't? I initially expected that everything would be transpiled, so that I wouldn't have to keep track of things like this, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: I believe TS is handling this much like the `Promise<T>` type. That is, it assumes that since you've entered it in, you've got a polyfill already. While `Number.isInteger` is trivially polyfilled, polyfills are not something TS wants to do. See for instance, [this comment about polyfills](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4031#issuecomment-125712496).

Comment: If this is the case, it would be nice if the IDE would alert me to the incompatibility of my code with my targeted ECMAScript version. I started using Number.isInteger() because Visual Studio offered it to me, and only later discovered that many (relatively modern) browsers don't support it.  Not sure what other "landmines" await!

Comment: Probably a good idea to use something like [es6-shim](https://github.com/paulmillr/es6-shim) which polyfills a lot of things that might be missing, at least until you know the browsers you're targeting support all of the features.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

TypeScript *transpiles* but does not *polyfill*. So one way to think of it is that anything that is not valid syntax in your `target` will be *transpiled* to a valid syntax. For example, when using the `class` keyword with your target set to `ES5`, it will transpile this:

```
class Greeter {
}
```

to this:

```
var Greeter = /** @class */ (function () {
    function Greeter() {
    }
    return Greeter;
}());
```

(You can play around more with this [here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/).)

On the other hand, it does not add missing functionality, which you'll have to *polyfill* yourself. `Number.isInteger()` is valid `ES5` syntax, it's just not functionality that exists in `ES5`. You can polyfill this yourself by importing [`babel-polyfill`](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/polyfill/) (which uses [`core-js`](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js) under the hood) or using a service like [polyfill.io](https://polyfill.io/v2/docs/).

**Note:** don't confuse the `lib` option with polyfills. This *does not* polyfill features. It simply tells TypeScript to act as if features from those ES versions are present, so it will type check them appropriately. You still need to handle the polyfill piece yourself for browsers that you support. If you don't specify the appropriate `lib`s, TypeScript will complain that it doesn't know what `Number.isInteger()` represents.

I'm not aware of a comprehensive list of which features TypeScript transpiles, but you can see a table for TypeScript+`core-js` polyfills [here](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/).
More reading on polyfills vs transpilation [here](https://hackernoon.com/polyfills-everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know-or-maybe-a-bit-less-7c8de164e423).

Answer (score 16):

The compiler supports features based on the lib that you tell it to use.
There are two ways to control which lib the compiler will use, by using the **`target`** and **`lib`** [compiler options](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html).

As it's written in the above link:

> If --lib is not specified a default library is injected. The default
>   library injected is:
>   ► For --target ES5: DOM,ES5,ScriptHost
>   ► For
>   --target ES6: DOM,ES6,DOM.Iterable,ScriptHost

All of the different libs are [part of the project](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/tree/master/lib).

If you are targeting `es3` or `es5` then you can't use `Number.isInteger()` as it's (as you stated) a `es6` feature.
If you have a polyfil for that then you can still target `es5` with the `es6` lib:

```
--target es5 --lib DOM,ES6,ScriptHost
```

Or you can just copy the definition for the [lib.es6.d.ts](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.es6.d.ts#L4394):

```
interface NumberConstructor {
    isInteger(number: number): boolean;
}
```

---

The reason that you can use things like `let`, `const`, `for/of` regardless of the target is that the compiler knows how to produce equivalent code even when the feature isn't supported for the chosen target.

For example:

```
const arr = [1, 2, 3];
for (let num of arr) {}
```

Is compiled to:

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3];
for (var _i = 0, arr_1 = arr; _i < arr_1.length; _i++) {
    var num = arr_1[_i];
}
```

If no target is specified.
As you can see, the `const` and `let` are turned into `var`s, and the `for/in` is turned into a regular `for`.

`Number.isInteger()` is something different, it's a functionality that doesn't exist in certain targets, like `Promise` and 'Symbol`.
The compiler won't add the polyfill, it's up to you to add it and then tell the compiler that it's there.

Comment: Thanks for your response. What I'm looking for is a way to know what categories of functionality will and won't be transpiled. I'm sure it makes sense to those working on the Typescript project, but at the moment it appears somewhat random to me. As a result, it becomes a game of guess and check.  Why is `for(var int of intArray)` fundamentally different than `Number.isInteger()`?

Comment: Oh. There's a good explenation for that. Check my revised answer.