# Typescript replaceAll not transpiled in es5

Tags: typescript, es5-compatiblity

I am using Typescript with `ESNEXT` (as of 2021) `replaceAll` in my code, because it is clearer than using a regexp.

I am transpiling to `es5`, but in the `dist` folder, in the traspiled js code, `replaceAll` remains as it is and there is a `TypeError: replaceAll is not a function` error.

I thought that Typescript would have traspiled it to es5, in a way that it works with es5. Why does it not do it? How can I fix this problem?

My TS config is:

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "strict": true,
        "target": "es5",
        "lib": [
            "ES2021"
        ],
        "sourceMap": true,
        "outDir": "../dist/server",
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "downlevelIteration": true,
        "paths": {
            "@/*": [
                "./*"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Provide your tsconfig file.

Comment: It is done @hoangdv

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What will Typescript transpile when targeting ES5 / ES3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42564130/what-will-typescript-transpile-when-targeting-es5-es3)

Comment: TypeScript only translates syntax and language features, not functionality.

Comment: @Jeff Bowman
Yes, it actually did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript will transpile modern JS *syntax* to ES5 but not do the polyfilling  (runtime apis).

You can use core-js for that. Add the following to your application entry point:

```
import 'core-js'; // <- at the top of your entry point
```

## More

https://www.npmjs.com/package/core-js

Comment: Thank you, I actually think that I will try nodejs 16 in my case, but your solution is the right one